# Converting from Int to Hex in Delphi and Java

Tags: java, delphi, int, hex

I have to convert the following Delphi code to Java:

```
function IntToHex(MyValue: Integer;  MinimumWidth: Integer): Ansistring;
begin
  AnsiStrings.FmtStr(Result, '%.*x', [MyValue, MinimumWidth]);
end;
```

The IntToHex function converts a *DecimalValue* integer into a hexadecimal format string of at least *MinimumWidth* characters wide.

I've implemented it in Java as:

```
public static String intToHex(int value)
    {
        return Integer.toHexString(value);
    }
```

Do I need in Java to indicate that the resulting string must contain at least the specified number of digits like in Delphi with parameter *MinimumWidth*? 
Did I already with my Java function implemented the full functionality from the Delphi IntToHeX-function?

Comment: No. If you want it to be of specific length, you must pad it.

Comment: DecimalValue is not decimal. It's just a number.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've also unterstood it as an Integer-parameter for the function. I took this exaple from the Delphi documentation.

Comment: A lot of people get confused over this issue. A number is a number. Decimal, hexadecimal, octal, etc. are all representations. So, Hex 20 represents the same number as decimal 32. Who knows what your actual Delphi code is though. The code you supplied is fake. It does not compile. Please don't show fake code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In my code the formal parameters have another names but there are also from type Int. The names for parameters in my question I took from [delphibasics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=IntToHex) site. The function is not fake. I tested it together with my converted function in Java and the both functions were returning the same values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right. Sorry, it was my mistake. I just noticed it only now. I changed the formal parameter names and forgot to do it also with parameters in square brackets. Now it should be compileable.

Comment: You should never go near that website it is of very low quality. That parameter is still not decimal so the name is really poor. You'd have been better off with your names!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, I think your solution should be to use String.format in Java
If you want hex numbers in the string you can use

```
String myFormattedString = String.format("%x", mynumber);
```

You can specify the lenght prepending it to the x, as

```
String myFormattedString = String.format("%4x", mynumber);
```

Where of course mynumber is a int or any other kind of valid number. 
If you want to pad with zeros you should use

```
String myFormattedString = String.format("%04x", mynumber);
```

You can use capital X to have capital letters in the resulting String

To have more information on the format option you can take a look at the following URL: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Hope this can help

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. The function is called from one place in code with parameters intToHex(intValue, 32) and in Java I also needed a result String from my function that has 32 position.